# How do I make a link *within* a page using Redmine (textile) markup

Tags: wiki, markup, redmine

How do I make links within a [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) Wiki page itself (which uses [Textile](http://textile.sitemonks.com/) markup syntax)? I can't find a solution [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineTextFormatting). Of course I can do `[[ThisPage#Foo|Foo]]` but I would rather do something simpler and shorter.

Comment: Did try [[#Foo|Foo]]?

Comment: Same question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839493/redmine-link-to-the-heading-on-the-same-page ; no answer there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest you could go is this:

```
[[ThisPage#Foo]]
```

But then the link will be called `ThisPage` instead of `Foo`...

There are no other constructs for this (at this time). I think your question make sense if you want to template the page and therefore you would like to avoid writing the name of the current page in it.

I can't see the burden of writing a page name, but I might be missing your particular use-case.

Comment: You can use [[ThisPage#Foo|Foo]] to fix link text